# I need help understanding how the summations were expanded

Tags: summation

[I am unable to understand how each of the summations in the first line were expanded and I am unable to understand how in the fourth line the summation was created. Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxhPE.png)

Answer (score 1):

The most dificult to see is $\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}i.$ Note that we are summing $n-1-(i-1)$ times the value $i.$ For this reason

$$\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}i=(n-1-i+1)i.$$ For identical reason 
$$\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}2=2(n-1-i+1).$$

On the other hand note that on the expression

$$i+i+1+\dots +i+(n-i-1)$$ there are $n-i$ times $i$ and moreover there is $$1+\dots +n-i-1=\sum_{j=1}^{n-i-1}j.$$

Comment: Also notice that the initial sum is simply $2+3+\cdots+(n+1-i)$ which value is obviously $(n+3-i)(n-i)/2$ by Gauss' trick for arithmetic sequences !

Comment: How do we get the $i-1$?

Comment: How many numbers are in the list $3,4,5,6?$ Is not $6-2?$ That is, the last one minus the first minus one.